# Regex Hex Chars

Tags: regex

How can I find only Hex chars with regex (0-9,a-f) and (m,n,o,k)?

Comment: This matches hex chars: `[0-9a-fA-F]` If you also want to match mnok, you can just list them in the square brackets: `[0-9a-fA-Fmnok]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```regex
[0-9a-fA-FmnokMNOK]
```

Explanation:

```
[                    #Match a single character present in the group (look below)
 0-9                 #All numbers from 0 to 9
    a-fA-F           #Characters from a to f (lowercase and uppercase)
          mnokMNOK   #The characters m, n, o and k (lowercase and uppercase)
                  ]  #End of character group
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/jT1iY3/3 - It also explains it to you on the right column.